# optimize query for last-auto-inc value

Tags: advantage-database-server

Sybase Advantage Database

I am doing a query

```
INSERT INTO nametable
SELECT * FROM nametable WHERE [indexkey]=32;
UPDATE nametable Set FieldName=1 
WHERE [IndexKey]=(SELECT max([indexKey]) FROM nametable);
```

The purpose is to copy a given record into a new record, and then update the newly created record with some new values. The "indexKey" is declared as autoinc and is the primary key to the table.

I am not sure if this can be achieved in a single statement with better speed or;;; suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved with a single statement but it will make the code more susceptible to schema changes. Suppose that there are 2 additional columns in the table besides the FieldName and the indexKey columns. Then the following statement will achieve your objective.

```
INSERT INTO nametable ( FieldName, Column2, Column3 )
SELECT 1, Column2, Column3 FROM nametable WHERE [indexkey]=32
```

However, if the table structure changes, this statement will need to be updated accordingly.

BTW, your original implementation is not safe in multi-user scenarios. The max( [indexKey] ) in the UPDATE statement may not be the one generated by the INSERT statement. Another user could have inserted another row between the two statements. To use your original approach, you should use the LastAutoInc() scalar.

```
UPDATE nametable Set FieldName=1
WHERE [IndexKey] = LastAutoInc( STATEMENT )
```